# Photoshop shows warning that some .otf fonts are missing in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, fonts

I need to use a font in Photoshop. My friends gave them to me in the `.otf` format. I installed those fonts in Windows 7 64 Bit, but at first they were not showing on my Photoshop font list.

I restarted Photoshop, and then they were installed, but when I open a PSD file, Photoshop shows a warning that those fonts are missing.

Comment: How did you install the fonts? Did you restart Photoshop afterwards?

Comment: Do the fonts work in other applications?

Comment: Yes I have restarted Photoshop and windows Both. I Selected all fonts and opened right click and press installed.

Comment: Now i noticed that fonts are installed but when I open PSD, Photoshop still show waring that those fonts are missing

Comment: Do they work in Word or Notepad?

Comment: @metalgearsolid I rewrote your question to include what we already know – since the problem is a different one now. In the future please [edit] it yourself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have restarted Photoshop since you installed the font haven't you? They won't show until you restart it.

Comment: User said that they restarted Photoshop, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The font family names may not match exactly, even though it's supposed to be the same font. Exactly what is Photoshop requesting and what does the Windows font viewer say (double click the font file from Explorer)?